# Cannot Install Wordpress Plugin (Download failed)

Tags: wordpress

i am using WordPress 3.6.1 and I have strange problem today. First I have to tell that my current website was copied from old website, both the WP files and database.

So in the current website, I try to install new plugin, but it returns error:

Downloading install package from http://downloads.wordpress.org/plugin/xml-sitemap-xml-sitemapcouk.zip…

Download failed. Could not open handle for fopen() to /home/k5841724/public_html/wp-content/uploads/xml-sitemap-xml-sitemapcouk.tmp

Then all my plugins are dissapered (Akismet, Hello Dolly, etc), and I can't install any plugin. Nothing wrong with my permission, /wp-content, /wp-includes, /wpcontent/uploads all are set to 755. Any idea what is the solution for this issue? Thanks.

**addition note:**
all my plugins folder (Akismet, etc) still there inside wp-content/plugins folder, but not appear in WP Dashboard.

Answer (score 0):

You should check permissions for folder `wp-content/uploads`

I think wordpress can't write to this folder. Set for this folder permission 777 and try again.

Comment: it still doesn't work, i also try to set permission 777 to wp-content and wp-content/uploads, but the error remains the same. Addition note: all my plugins folder (Akismet, etc) still there inside wp-content/plugins folder, but not appear in WP Dashboard.

Answer (score 0):

I have experienced the same error with plugin installation.
In my case it was very informative to change WP_DEBUG to true in my wp-config.php file.

After doing so I have noticed the error message, telling me that open function is disabled due to security reasons.

Try changing your php.ini settings so that disable_functions doesn't contain fopen